# how can i fix this error in my Webview Android Project

Tags: java, android, xml, webview, android-webview

i have a problem, that when i start the app then comes an error: **net::ERR_CACHE_MISS** i want an android app that implements a WebView so i am able to have my website on my app. Can someone please help me how to fix this problem

MainActivity.java

```java
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("https://snoopti.de");
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

i tried to ask ChatGPT but its doesnt gave me helpful code

Answer (score 0):

Can you add Internet permission in your android manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```